# how to run multiple spec files in cypress 10?

Tags: angularjs, cypress

I am using **cypress 10.0.0**, I try to integrate multiple test (spec) file on cypress.config.ts, is possible on new **cypress update** ??

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
    supportFolder: 'cypress/support',
    fixturesFolder: 'cypress/fixtures',
    screenshotsFolder: 'cypress/screenshots',
    videosFolder: 'cypress/videos',
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:5200',
    retries: {
      runMode: 5,
      openMode: 5,
    }
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, create a new e2e spec that just imports all other specs.

**cypress/e2e/all.cy.js**

```js
import './spec1.cy.js'
import './spec2.cy.js'
import './spec3.cy.js'
```

Then chose `all.cy.js` as the spec to open in the runner.

Answer (score 1):

To run all spec files together you have to use the command:

```js
npx cypress run
```